# How to show second content projected in Angular with ng-content?

Tags: angular

I have created a custom component in Angular that projects content provided:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-box',
  template: '<ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>',
})
export class BoxComponent {    
  constructor() {}
}
```

I use it like this in application.component.html:

```
<app-box>
  <div body>1</div>
</app-box>
```

Causing digit 1 to be displayed.

Now, I would like to pass **variable** number of items to the app-box component **in the template**, and display them **selectively** in the app-box component.

Something like this:

```
app-box component:

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-box',
  template: '<ng-content select="[body]:nth-of-type(2)"></ng-content>', /* :nth-of-type(2) */
})
export class BoxComponent {    
  constructor() {}
}

app.component.ts:

<app-box>
   <div body>1</div>
   <div body><b>2</b></div>
   <div body><i>3</i></div>
</app-box>
```

The code presented should show the second div (digit 2).

How to show specific div by its number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with multiple, variable number of items, I'd do something like the following:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
   <app-box itemToShow="i">
      <div class="i">1</div>
      <div class="i">2</div>
      <div class="i">3</div>
   </app-box>
</div>
```

Then, in your `app-box` component, you can bind the selector to the `itemToShow` input.

```html
<ng-content select=".{{itemToShow}}"></ng-content>
```

Comment: I guess I'm assuming that it's ok for the parent to specify which child to show...

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure i understand you'r problem but i will try.

You want to add more than 1 element in `ng-content` right ?

[Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection)

You can specify some content in `ng-content`

```
 Default:
    <ng-content></ng-content>

 Question:
    <ng-content select="[question]"></ng-content>
```

And use it like that :

```html
    <my-component>
        <p Question>
            How are you ?
        </p>
        <p>
            Im Default
        </p>
    </my-component>
```

not native speaker :) hope you understand me

Comment: Thank you Julien for answer. The question is about more advanced usage of content projection.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry then.